# Using MUP returned a container error

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean, mup

When I used the following config deploying to digitalocean, I did a `$ mup setup` with no errors and then ran `$ mup deploy` and everything went well until it tried to prepare bundle...what am I missing here?

This is the error I'm getting with the following config when deploying...
[image]

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
   one: {
    host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    username: 'root',
    pem: "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
  }
},

app: {
  name: 'hotel',
  path: '../hotel', 
  // this is my local path to the application root

servers: {
  one: {},
},

buildOptions: {
  serverOnly: true,
},

env: {
  ROOT_URL: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
  MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor',
},

docker: {
  image: 'abernix/meteord:base',
},

// Show progress bar while uploading bundle to server
// You might need to disable it on CI servers
enableUploadProgressBar: true
},

mongo: {
  version: '3.4.1',
  servers: {
    one: {}
   }
 }
};
```